# How to disable javascript in chromedp?

Tags: go, chromedp

I want to disable javascript in https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp

any allocator flag can I put in the config? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line option: `--blink-settings=scriptEnabled=false`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("blink-settings", "scriptEnabled=false"),
    )
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = chromedp.NewContext(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    var res []byte
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate(`https://twitter.com/`),
        chromedp.FullScreenshot(&res, 100),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    os.WriteFile("screenshot.png", res, 0644)
}
```

FYI, the list of available `blink-settings` can be found here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/09372ea8ec2ab6363ccad6a4847a1c9da560b29d:out/Debug/gen/third_party/blink/renderer/core/settings_macros.h;l=1535

Comment: Thanks @Zeke Lu your solution always legit!:D